# The action 'show' could not be found for EntryLevelsController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes

Am facing a strange error of "AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'show' could not be found for EntryLevelsController)"
I have not defined the 'show' action because I don't need it. I have instead defined custom routes in a collection within the resource entry_levels as shown below:

```
resources :entry_levels do
  collection do
    get 'create_entry_level'
    post 'create_entry_level'
    get 'edit_entry_levell'
    post 'edit_entry_level'
    get 'update_entry_level'
    post 'update_entry_level'
    get 'delete_entry_level'
    post 'delete_entry_level'
    get 'entry_level_cancel'
    post 'entry_level_cancel'
    get 'change_priority'
    post 'create_entry_level'
  end
end
```

The strange thing is that rails generates urls for index, show , create, delete, update and edit actions as if I have defined a 'resource :entry_levels' somewhere in my routes.rb file which is not the case. I have no idea why the error about the show action keeps popping up.

My rake routes is shown below:

```
create_entry_level_entry_levels GET    /entry_levels/create_entry_level                                                              entry_levels#create_entry_level
                                                         POST   /entry_levels/create_entry_level                                                         entry_levels#create_entry_level
                      edit_entry_levell_entry_levels GET    /entry_levels/edit_entry_levell                                                           entry_levels#edit_entry_levell
                       edit_entry_level_entry_levels POST   /entry_levels/edit_entry_level                                                            entry_levels#edit_entry_level
                     update_entry_level_entry_levels GET    /entry_levels/update_entry_level                                                          entry_levels#update_entry_level
                                                         POST   /entry_levels/update_entry_level                                                          entry_levels#update_entry_level
                     delete_entry_level_entry_levels GET    /entry_levels/delete_entry_level                                                         entry_levels#delete_entry_level
                                                         POST   /entry_levels/delete_entry_level                                                          entry_levels#delete_entry_level
                     entry_level_cancel_entry_levels GET    /entry_levels/entry_level_cancel                                                         entry_levels#entry_level_cancel
                                                         POST   /entry_levels/entry_level_cancel                                                        entry_levels#entry_level_cancel
                          change_priority_entry_levels GET    /entry_levels/change_priority                                                              entry_levels#change_priority
                                                         POST   /entry_levels/create_entry_level                                                          entry_levels#create_entry_level
                                          entry_levels GET    /entry_levels                                                                              entry_levels#index
                                                         POST   /entry_levels                                                                              entry_levels#create
                                       new_entry_level GET    /entry_levels/new                                                                          entry_levels#new
                                      edit_entry_level GET    /entry_levels/:id/edit                                                                     entry_levels#edit
                                           entry_level GET    /entry_levels/:id                                                                           entry_levels#show
                                                         PUT    /entry_levels/:id                                                                           entry_levels#update
                                                         DELETE /entry_levels/:id                                                                          entry_levels#destroy
```

Comment: when you are getting this error? I mean on which url.

Comment: @maximus, the error pops when I call an action found in the entry_levels controller when I select a course from a dropdown select box.am using ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You setup is a little untypical. Here are a few hints.

```
resources :entry_levels do
  # restful actions are automatically included, that is 
  # :index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update and :destroy

  put 'change_priority', on: :member # see the generated route and helpers with `rake routes`. A PUT request states that you are updating an existing resource.
end
```

It's also good to know that you can check which routes are generated by your setup by running [**`$ rake routes`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#seeing-existing-routes-with-rake).

Comment: ok, but does it mean I should then write the custom routes above  'resources :entry_levels'? I also thought that 'member do' is for nested objects? I have posted my rake routes in the question. Thanx I'll really appreciate.

Comment: The [Rails guides on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) are an excellent read. My point was that you maybe wouldn't need the non-restful custom routes you're offering, but instead could use the standard restful ones for such standard operations.

Comment: Surely I must read about routing because I it has been a pain for some time. so how would you put the routes then?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it came up for one of my searches, so I want to add to possible answers.

I get that error when I have a post without a corresponding get.  When that happens I either define the post as a get (if it works that way), or I create a match entry in routes.rb to send the user to the root page if the post comes in as a get (for example if the user is logged out):

```
 match "entry_levels/create_entry_level" => "home#index", via: :get
```

In this case however, the problem seems to be that you have create_entry_level defined as a post twice.  Never done that, but is probably messing you up.  You forgot to change the create_entry_level to 'change_priority'.